# expo-sqlite returning undefined is not an object in excuteSql function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have this code that should log users in in a

> React Native App

Each time I clicked on the

> Login Button

It always displayed this error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE email = ? AND password = ?", [student.email, student.password]).then')

This is the code I wrote

```
    //The database connection
    import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
//const db = SQLite.openDatabase('db.db');
//import SQLite from "react-native-sqlite-storage";
//SQLite.DEBUG(true);
//SQLite.enablePromise(true);

const database_name = "mySchool.db";
const database_version = "1.0";
const database_displayname = "Biometric attendance base";
const database_size = 200000;

const db = SQLite.openDatabase(database_name, database_version, database_name, database_size)

export default db;

    // Import db connection for use
    import db from '../Database';
    getStudent = () => {
        const student = {
          password: this.state.password,
          email: this.state.email,
        };

        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE email = ? AND password = ?", [
            student.email,
            student.password,
          ], ).then(([tx, results]) => {
            alert(results);
            if (results.rows.length > 0) {
              let row = results.rows.item(0);
              this.props.navigation.navigate('StudentLogin', { data: row });
              //resolve(row);
            } else {
              alert('Incorrect email and password comnbination');
            }
          });
        });
```

This is the code that will run whenever I clicked on Login button

Comment: Can you `console.log(results)` and present the output

Comment: and show where your `db` gets declared

Comment: It was imported at the top.

Comment: ok, than log `db` to the console, and post the result

Comment: Have updated the question. Actually, am using snack.expo.io to create the app. So i don't know where to find the console.log

Comment: `console.log` is some of the basic to understand, before getting started with higher level building of an Application. If you run this in Browser, you have to open the browser console. But this is another question and answered a thousand of times everywhere.

Comment: further, I don't think your db's name is 'mySchool.db'. I think its 'mySchool'

Answer (score 0):

[Referenze](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/)

```js
db.transaction((tx) => {
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE email = ? AND password = ?", [
    student.email,
    student.password,
], (tx, results) => {
    console.log(result);
})
});
```